# Simple form with custom resource name different than object class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Question - I have the following setup

job_offer.rb

```
class JobOffer
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :jobs
```

Simple form form:

```
= simple_form_for [@company, @job], url: jobs_path(@job) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12
      .form-group
        = f.input :title
```

Now when I save the form I get the following error:

```
No route matches [PATCH] "/jobs.1"
```

I think that's because the wrong URL is generated. How do I give simple form the correct url? I could change the ActiveModel name in the class. But I am not sure I should do that.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can list your routes with `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for job_path(@job), not jobs_path

Answer (score 0):

You can specify custom resource name by passing `as` option to the `simple_form_for` helper

```rb
= simple_form_for [@company, @job], as: :custom_resource_name, url: job_path(@job) do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-12.col-md-12
      .form-group
        = f.input :title
```

And in your case you have typo in url helper name. Must be singular:

`job_path(@job)` instead of `jobs_path(@job)`